# бот не находит chat_id в telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

это жесть какая то. честное слово. нигде не могу найти об этом информацию больше, кроме как в официальной документации. меня интересует функция `sendMessage`. в ней есть описание `chat_id`.

```
chat_id     Integer or String   Yes     Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername)
```

это значит что можно отправлять сообщения по `username`, типа `@proteir`. но ошибка приходит, почему? это же в api написано.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать

```
message.chat.id
```

Возможно в этом ошибка

Comment: хорошо, попробую, спасибо. позже отпишусь.

Comment: что то я не понял вашего совета? функция api принимает параметр, в чем ошибка?